# Swift compile-time availability: non-available case

Tags: ios, swift, compile-time, availability

There is nice @available attribute in swift to test availability in compile-time.
E.g. HKQuantityTypeIdentifierAppleExerciseTime identifier is available only since iOS 9.3,
so if we want to use it we need check availability like this:

```
@available(iOS 9.3, *)
public static let supportedTypes = [
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned,
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifierAppleExerciseTime
]
```

but is it possible to add also case when identifier is not available? 
To define same constant in iOS < 9.3 as:

```
// iOS < 9.3 case:
public static let supportedTypes = [
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned
]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can declare the variable and initialize it with `#available`:

```
public static let supportedTypes: [String] = {
    guard #available (iOS 9.3, *) else { 
        return [ HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned ] 
    }

   return [
       HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned,
       HKQuantityTypeIdentifierAppleExerciseTime
   ]
}()
```

You are essentially trying to declare one of two variables with the same name and different default values, depending on a condition. I think it's more straightforward to declare a single variable once, and then assign its default value depending on the same condition. Same goes with classes basically.

Comment: it compiles with error: Unable to infer closure return type in current context

Comment: Yeah sorry, that was from the top of my head and I forgot to explicitly specify the `let` type (which, as the compiler complains, can't be inferred from the context). I've updated my answer with a `: [String]` — feel free to try again now.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to use #available like this:

```
static func setupTypes() -> [String] {
    if #available(iOS 9.3, *) {
        return [
            HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned,
            HKQuantityTypeIdentifierAppleExerciseTime
        ]
    else{
        return [
            HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned,
        ]
    }    
}

public static let supportedTypes:[String] = MyClass.setupTypes()
```

But it is additional complication and also can't be applied to whole classes, so question is still open.

Comment: Please, don't think I'm defending my own solution — rather trying to understand what you need to achieve. I've updated my answer with my thoughts regarding complications, please let me know if you want to provide more context on why you need to follow this specific way of doing things, to help me and others understand what you are looking for.

Comment: @Alex  your answer is ok and I've upvoted it. But still waiting for other  solutions. E.g. consider non-avalable case for whole class.

Comment: Ok, sure — although for classes the same rule applies I guess: rather than defining one of two classes of the same name, you may want to define one and adjust its behaviour depending on API availability.